# TensorFlow and oneDNN

Tags: tensorflow

After installing `tensorflow==2.9.1` and running it for the first time I got the following message:

```py
2022-08-19 11:51:23.381523: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] 
This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) 
to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  
AVX2 AVX512F AVX512_VNNI FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate 
compiler flags.
```

This message is a bit confusing. At a first glance, it seems like a bad thing. But if you read it carefully, you realize it's actually a good thing. It's using all those nice extensions in "*performance-critical operations*". But then the last sentence makes it sound not so good, because they are not enabled in "*other operations*" (whatever they are).

---

Searching the above message on the interwebs I came across [Intel® Optimization for TensorFlow* Installation Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide.html) which said:

> If your machine has AVX512 instruction set supported please use the below packages for better performance.
>
> pip install intel-tensorflow-avx512==2.9.1 # linux only

Since my box supports AVX512, I've installed `intel-tensorflow-avx512==2.9.1` and now got this message:

```py
2022-08-19 11:43:00.187298: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] 
This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) 
to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  
AVX512_VNNI
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate 
compiler flags.
```

Hmm...

---

So, my questions are:

1. Since Intel "optimized" version of TensorFlow only "complains" of using AVX512_VNNI in "*performance-critical sections*", does that mean it's using AVX2, AVX512F and FMA everywhere, including all "*other operations*"? Or does it mean it's not using them at all?
2. If it's not using them at all, does it mean it's "inferior" to the official version of TensorFlow and there is no point in using it?
3. BONUS QUESTION: Why are those cool AVX2/512F/512_VNNI and FMA instructions only enabled in "*performance-critical sections*" and not for all "*other operations*"?

Comment: Could you please have a look at the instruction steps mentioned in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#linux) link to install tensorflow in your system.

Comment: @TFer2 I took a look. Was there anything specific you wanted me to see? I did install tf with pip. Just didn't use all the conda nonsense.